# what is tx-ccq index in an AP and Client device?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

As I know, Txccq is a quality index, summarizing several conditions. What are the constituent factors leading to the Txccq low period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What are the constituent factors leading to the Txccq low period?

The exact algorithm used will depend on the vendor of the access point you are using.

Below are the definitions from a couple of different vendors.

---

#### What is CCQ and how are the values determined?

> Client Connection Quality (CCQ) is a value in percent that shows how
>   effective the bandwidth is used regarding the theoretically maximum
>   available bandwidth.
>
> CCQ is weighted average of values Tmin/Treal, that get calculated for
>   every transmitted frame, where Tmin is time it would take to transmit
>   given frame at highest rate with no retries and Treal is time it took
>   to transmit frame in real life (taking into account necessary retries
>   it took to transmit frame and transmit rate).

Source [Manual:Wireless FAQ](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Wireless_FAQ#What_is_CCQ_and_how_are_the_values_determined.3F)

---

#### What are TX rate, RX rate, CCQ, Noise Level?

> CCQ is an index that evaluates the wireless Client Connection Quality.
>   It takes into account transmit errors, latency, and throughput while
>   evaluating the ratio of successfully transmitted packets against the
>   re-transmitted ones; it also takes into account the current rate ratio
>   against the highest specified rate.
>
> The level is based on a percentage value where 100% represents a
>   perfect link state.
>
> Noise Level displays the value of the noise signal that was received.

Source [What are TX rate, RX rate, CCQ, Noise Level?](http://www.compex.com.sg/kbase/tx-rate-rx-rate-ccq-noise-level/)

Comment: Thanks. I think the second one is more applicable to the AP that I'm using.  I also wish to know "What are the constituent factors leading to the Txccq low period?"

Comment: That's in the answer - transmit errors, high latency, low throughput and high noise level will all contribute to a low score.